# Manjaro 18.0.4 Illyria installer waits on welcome

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, manjaro

I'm trying to install Manjaro linux as dual boot with W10 on lenovo ideapad miix320 - 10icr convertible laptop.

I managed to boot from usb into OS. When starting installer it keeps waiting on welcome screen with message "waiting for 1 module(s).(xxx seconds)"

Is it how it's supposed to be ? How long I should wait ?

It also took like 5-7 minutes on grub menu to boot. But system is running fast once booted.

[image: waiting for module]

After reburning usb boot device everything works. It gave warnings on same screen to about power source being disconnected and wifi not being connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some bug with usb installer. It started working as I made new bootable usb with the same image.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not normal.

Linux has a "virtual console" feature: by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>function key</kbd> you can switch between multiple console views. Typically, when the system is running normally, either F1 or F6 has the default GUI if it's enabled, and of the remaining, the first 4 or 5 usually contain login prompts for text-based sessions, and the rest are unused.

With Linux OS installation programs, there is a common convention of using these virtual consoles to provide the installer's event log and/or a shell prompt for advanced troubleshooting if required. So, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> and start pressing the function keys one after another: typically F1 is the view you're in now, and the subsequent views might contain the installer's log and/or a root prompt you might use to find out more information on what is causing the delay. Note that switching in and out of graphics mode may take a few seconds, so don't be too hasty.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i've a another hard drive for backups, these hard drive caused the problem, only disconnect the disk and run one more time the installer